# How to write query method for sorting the results based on the field which is part of parent entity spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In spring data JPA we can write query methods to execute query. I have two entities

```
class A {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_field")
    private B b;
}

class B {
    @Id
    @KeyField
    @Column
    private String id; 

    private String b_field
}
```

I want to write a query method "findByNameOrderByb_field" i.e find all the rows  having name as provided and order the results on the basis of class B's field i.e b_field. Writing above function is not returning ordered results. Is there any way I can write this orderby query method in spring boot.

```
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, String> {

    List<A> findByNameOrderByb_field(String name);
}
```

the above function is not returning ordered results based on B's b_field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access properties of B you have to include the field name of B in the declaration of the query method.

```
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, String> {

    List<A> findByNameOrderByb_b_field(String name);
}
```

More information how SpringData resolves nested Properties can be found under:

[Query Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)